# Как убрать ошибку в PHP7?

Tags: php, php7

В коде `return $query['Count'] ?? 0;` PHPStorm подсвечивает оператор `??` как ошибку хотя, у меня настроен OpenServer: Apache-7.0, PHP-7.0, MySQL-7.0.

Что можно сделать?

[image: Ошибка в коде?]

Comment: У вас выбрана сборка 5.4, а данный оператор работает на 7 версии. Для этого зайдите в настройки проекта и выберите 7 версию.

Comment: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/08/29/0012/1595/792123/23/6f881f4428.jpg

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос - решен!:)